# How to give the bottom half of a shape a different color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes

I'm creating a round label for a product and have a half of a round shape on the top portion of the label. At the bottom of that half round I'm trying to make it a different color but cannot figure out how to isolate just that portion. I'm new to Illustrator and can figure this out so much easier in Photoshop but need the curved text only Illustrator can do, so I thought I'd create the entire label in Illustrator. thank you.

Comment: Hey jmichelle, welcome to GD.SE! Can you edit your post to include a question? Also, if you can include a screenshot of what you're trying to do, it will make it easier for folks here to understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using Gradients of some sort Shapes only exist in 1 color in Vector applications.

Unlike a raster application like Photoshop which tells the file this pixel is red next pixel blue, etc a vector application says this shape is created by these vectors and has these properties.

What you'll need to do is create multiple shapes if you want them to have different colors.